# CSS nth-last-child confusion

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am really confused with nth-child when I am trying to make something with this...

I have figured out how can I make every third frame to have margin-right set on zero!

```
#thumbnailWrap .thumbnail:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

However I cannot manage to figureout how to make last child to reset margin-bottom back to zero.

I was trying and trying but then I simply typed this:

```
#thumbnailWrap .thumbnail:nth-last-child(1), #thumbnailWrap .thumbnail:nth-last-child(2), #thumbnailWrap .thumbnail:nth-last-child(3) {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Because I've got bored. Now if you wont mind, please help me and teach me, how could I do this more simplified and better :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the last 3 children then use this

```
#thumbnailWrap .thumbnail:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: thank  you man ! Exactly what I wanted.
Still I don't understand how this works :D 

Thanks for correct answer.

Comment: the '-n' is telling it to start at the bottom and work up, and the +3 tells it to do that 3  times. If you wanted to start at the second to last you would use -1n+3. Also, with both of these you can use odd and even as keywords!

Comment: @NenaddvL this article here might help you http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/